# Gitlab: Can group maintainers access private group projects?

Tags: gitlab

I am unclear the different between developer and maintainers. I am wondering if maintainers can access private projects while developers cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both developers and maintainers can access private projects.

The main difference between the two roles is that maintainers can **create**, edit and delete private projects, whereas developers cannot:

[image: Differences]

Maintainers can also add new team members, push to protected branches (along with enabling/disabling branch protection), and a few other features such as editing pages and user comments. The following is a full list of things Maintainers can do that Developers cannot:

[image: Maintainer features]

Comment: Can developers push to private group repos? Or is that just for maintainers?